# Favicon not displaying when deployed

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, django-staticfiles

I have deployed a Django website on Pythonanywhere. The favicon worked on my local server but not on my Pythonanywhere site.

The code in my base.html is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'fixtureapp/style.css' %}">
<link href="{% static 'images/scc.ico?' %}" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

I've shown the stylesheet link as this is working so static is set up ok. iamges/scc.ico is in the same static file.

I get the error

2021-03-10 14:52:43,422: Not Found: /favicon.ico

Comment: Django does *not* serve static files on production.

Comment: There is also a question mark at the end of the `.ico`?

Comment: If removing the question mark doesn't help, try going directly to the URL for the favicon and see if it's actually there.

Answer (score -1):

I did encounter the same issue. Changing the file extension from .ico to .png worked for me. This works if the favicon image used is converted to png.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31992845)